# I have a problem with sorting my arraylist using the method Collections.sort - I keep getting an error message

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

```
Note: EarthquakeTester.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

I look it up on my shell then my message states this

```
javac -Xlint EarthquakeTester.java
EarthquakeTester.java:80: warning: [unchecked] unchecked method invocation: method sort in class Collections is applied to given types
          Collections.sort(earthquakeArrayList);
                          ^
  required: List<T>
  found: ArrayList<Earthquake>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Comparable<? super T> declared in method <T>sort(List<T>)
```

I am not sure what to do here.

This code here is from tester class below.

```
         ArrayList<Earthquake> earthquakeArrayList = new ArrayList<>(); 

if(mag < 3)
          earthquakeArrayList.add(new NonClassified(TimeAndDate, lat, lon, mag, id, place));

else
 earthquakeArrayList.add(new Classified(TimeAndDate, lat, lon, mag, id, place));
     
 Collections.sort(earthquakeArrayList);
```

The code under here is from earthquake class

```
public abstract class Earthquake implements Comparable 
.....
...
...

      public int compareTo(Object obj)
 {
     Earthquake other = (Earthquake) obj;
     
     if(this.magnitude < other.getMagnitude() )
     {return 1;}
     else if(this.magnitude > other.getMagnitude())
             {return -1 ;}
     else 
         return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: How is earthquakeArrayList defined?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define earthquakeArrayList as parametrized ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<Earthquake> earthquakeArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```